# What are equations with a degree more than 3 called?

Tags: polynomials, terminology

Sorry if I am using the incorrect terminology. I am beginning to learn Mathematics. I had it in school and college but have forgotten most of it, so please be gentle with me if my questions are stupid.

I recall we have a nomenclature for equations based on the highest exponent of the variables in it.

1. Those with a degree of 1 are called linear equations.

   $$2x + 7 = -5$$
2. With a degree 2 are called quadratic equations.

   $$4x^2 + 2x + 3 = 0$$
3. With a degree of 3 are called cubic.

   $$x^3 + 2x^2 + x - 2 = 0$$
4. There was a universal term applied to all equations with a degree of 4 or above and that's what I forget and that's my question. What are these polynomials / equations called? What's the blanket term?

   $$7y^4 - 2y^3 + y^2 - y = 121$$

Comment: polynomial equations (covers the lot)

Comment: @DougM Many thanks. Would you like to put that down as an answer, please?

Comment: Quartic, quintic, sextic, septic, ... polynomial.

Comment: The convenience frequency of having terminology starts diminishing really fast.  Polynomial covers the lot (including constants, linear, quadratics, and cubics).  Constants and lines are distinct and have special properties deserving their own terms.  Quadratics and cubics are common enough to make their own terms worthwhile.   But higher powers... not so much.  You can call them quartics, and quintic, sextic, septic, octic etc. but most people would think you are pushing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The names ''quartic'' and ''quintic'' for polynomials of degree $4$ and $5$ are commonly used (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function), and [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuinticEquation.html)). Other terms such as sextic, etc... are less used and usually, for degree $n>5$ the expression *$n-$degree polynomial* is used.

Answer (score 3):

Fourth degree is called quartic.  Fifth quintic.  Sixth sextic, and so on via latin.  However I think must people who would use "dodecic equation" rather than "12th degree polynomial" would be derided as pompous jackasses.

Quadratic and cubic are common enough to justify terminology.  Quartic and quintic can have special theorems and the terminology lends an air of cleverness if not over done.  Sextic is really pushing it.

Comment: And septic polynomials are just gutter talk.

Comment: Thank you. I found all the answers very useful but I am not qualified enough yet to rank them and judge the best, so I am merely marking the one that came in the first as the correct one. I did find your answer very useful, though. So, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

They are overall called polynomials, but there are names for the individual types:
$$2x+7=5 \text{ - linear}$$ 
$$2x^2+3x+2=0 \text{ - quadratic}$$ 
$$2x^3+4x^2+3x+2=0 \text{ - cubic}$$ 
$$2x^4+x^3+4x^2+3x+2=0 \text{ - quartic}$$ 
$$2x^5+5x^4+x^3+4x^2+3x+2=0 \text{ - quintic}$$ 
And it goes on, with sextic, septic, octic, and others, but it is so much more convenient to just call them polynomials that the only term greater than cubic I have heard is quartic, and the only terms greater than cubic that I have read (in a different mathematical context) are quartic and quintic. So, in general, polynomials is the term you'd want to use. To talk about a sextic equation, for example, you might talk of a polynomial of the sixth degree, or for any equation in general, a polynomial of the $n$th degree.

If you want to read more about the quartic, the quintic, and others, see [this website](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function) (for quartic), [this website](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintic_function) (for quintic), [this website](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sextic_equation) (for sextic), [this website](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Septic_equation) (for septic), and [this website](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial) (for polynomials in general).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Many thanks. I found your answer very helpful. I am marking the right one simply based on the fact that it came in the earliest. I found all the answers very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

For 1 degree ➡ linear equations
For 2 degree ➡ quadratic equations
For 3 degree ➡ cubic
For 4 degree ➡ quartic 
For 5 degree ➡ quintic
For 6 degree ➡ sextic
For 7 degree ➡ septic
For 8 degree ➡ octatic
For 9 degree ➡ nonatic
For10 degree ➡ decatic
This ten and useful .I know but forget the others.